# short[] array to EMGU Image , fastest way?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

I have an array of `Int16[19200]`
I want to turn it into an `Image[160,120,1]`

What is the fastest way of doing this?

I need to do it at 120fps, so it needs to be really efficient.
Thanks
SW

Answer (score 2):

Found it:

```
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(dataArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            IntPtr imageHeaderForBytes = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MIplImage)));
            CvInvoke.cvInitImageHeader(
                  imageHeaderForBytes,
                  new Size(160, 120),
                  Emgu.CV.CvEnum.IPL_DEPTH.IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1, 0, 4);
            Marshal.WriteIntPtr(
                  imageHeaderForBytes,
                  (int)Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(MIplImage), "imageData"),
                  handle.AddrOfPinnedObject());

            CvInvoke.cvCopy(imageHeaderForBytes, EMGUImage.Ptr, IntPtr.Zero);

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(imageHeaderForBytes);
            handle.Free();
```